# Simple javascript- how to make code more efficient?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use javascript to filter by the age of a group of people. I have a list of people in an object, and a list of buttons that when people click on allow them to filter by age.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="people">
    <button id="all">All</button>
    <button id="tenunder">10 and under</button>
    <button id="twentyunder">20 and under</button>
    <button id="over20">over 20</button>
</div>
<div id="people-list"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
    var people = [{
    name: "Derik Scott",
    age: 10,
    dob: "June 11, 1989"
}, {
    name: "Amy Sanchez",
    age: 12,
    dob: "January 11, 1989"
}, {
    name: "Kara Patil",
    age: 25,
    dob: "April 20, 1989"
}, {
    name: "Jasmine Lucas",
    age: 20,
    dob: "December 1, 1989"
}];

var peopleDiv = document.getElementById('people');

peopleDiv.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clicked = e.target;
    var clickedId = clicked.id;
    var peopleListDiv = document.getElementById('people-list');
    clicked.className = "active";

    peopleListDiv.innerHTML = "";

    switch (clickedId) {
        case "all":
            for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i += 1) {
                peopleListDiv.innerHTML += people[i].name + "<br />";
            }
            break;
        case "tenunder":
            clicked.setAttribute("class", "active");
            for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i += 1) {
                if (people[i].age <= 10) {
                    peopleListDiv.innerHTML += people[i].name + "<br />";
                }
            }
            break;
        case "twentyunder":
            for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i += 1) {
                if (people[i].age <= 20) {
                    peopleListDiv.innerHTML += people[i].name + "<br />";
                }
            }
            break;
        case "over20":
            for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i += 1) {
                if (people[i].age > 20) {
                    peopleListDiv.innerHTML += people[i].name + "<br />";
                }
            }
            break;
    }
});
```

Is there any way to make this code more efficient?

Comment: What do you mean with more 'efficient'? Better performance, more readable, Less lines?

Comment: There are some nice answers here. So I just write this one in addition. If you store the dob of each person inside the object, I guess it is a better way, to calculate the age when using it. So it's possible to keep the age up to date dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use built in filter and map array method to have cleaner code.

```
var people = [
{name : 'John Doe', age : 21},
{name : 'Jane Doe', age : 19},
{name : 'Baby Doe', age : 2},
{name : 'kid Doe', age : 11}
];

var peopleDiv = document.getElementById('people');

peopleDiv.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clicked = e.target;
    var clickedId = clicked.id;
    var peopleListDiv = document.getElementById('people-list');
    clicked.className = "active";

    var peopleToDisplay = getPeople(people, clickedId)
        .map(function (people) { return people.name; })
        .join('<br />');

    peopleListDiv.innerHTML = peopleToDisplay;    

});
var getPeople = function(people, clickedId) {
     switch (clickedId) {
        case "all":
            return people;
        case "tenunder":
            return people.filter(peopleUnderTen);
        case "twentyunder":
            return people.filter(peopleUnderTwenty);   
        case "over20":
            return people.filter(peopleOverTwenty);
    }   
};

var peopleUnderAge = function (age, people) {
    return function (people) {
        return people.age <= age;
    };
};

var peopleUnderTen = peopleUnderAge(10);
var peopleUnderTwenty = peopleUnderAge(20);
var peopleOverTwenty = function (people) { return people.age > 20; };
```

a working [jsfiddle exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/royto/6d74f4xu/)

Comment: I have updated my code to use curry function `function peopleUnderAge = function (age, people)return function (people) {
        return people.age <= age;
    };
};`
Usage : 
`var peopleUnderTen = peopleUnderAge(10);`

Comment: using .apply you could avoid those three functions at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Efficient as in execution time? The most obvious bottleneck here is appending to `element.innerHTML` in every iteration, you may push the names into an array and write them once after the loop:

```
var names = [];
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i += 1) {
    if (people[i].age > 20) {
        names.push( people[i].name );
    }
}
peopleListDiv.innerHTML = names.join("<br />");
```

You could also use `Array.prototype.filter` to filter the array, which may not really be faster, but clearly demonstrates the intent of your code at a glance:

```
 var names = people.filter( function( person ){
    return person.age > 20;
 })
 .map(function( person ){ return person.name });
 peopleListDiv.innerHTML = names.join("<br />");
```

Edit: If you feel adventerous and like short code go with ES2015!

```
 peopleListDiv.innerHTML = people.filter(person => person.age > 20)
 .map(person => person.name).join('<br>')
```